# Non-exact/related searches with MongoDB: find() vs $search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, search, mongodb-query, full-text-search

Hope everyone is doing great.

I had a bit of a "weird" question regarding doing non-exact/related searches with MongoDB.

I'm building a web application with a sort of "search engine" search bar if you will (I.e.: people input stuff and the results are documents related to that search instead of exact results), and I'm having a difficult time deciding the best approach.

Recently I discovered about MongoDB's full text search and it's been amazing so far in terms of what I want to achieve. However, as my search functionalities get more complex (adding stuff like sorting, pagination, etc.) I notice a lack of documentation on best practices in comparison to using `find()` queries. I mean, I know there are aggregation pipeline stages for doing those types of functionalities, but I have found the amount of proper examples kinda lacking.

Taking that into consideration, I've starting to consider changing my approach to using `find()` queries, but I can't seem to find examples of people using them for non-exact/related matches in the same way of what full text search can achieve. How would you even do that with `find()`? Would you use a more elaborated Regex or something similar? Is it even worth the try?

I would love to hear your anecdotes, specially as your search features became more complex, to ensure that the app remains performant. Do you swear by full text search? Or have you achieved search engine-like search using the good old `find()`? If so, how?

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Basically what i know in mongodb full text search is come with 2 types.

- mongoDB atlas search
- On-premise text search

To perform text search you can learn more on below ref docs

REFERENCE: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/link-text-indexes/